# Getting the top 5 start-stop points

Tags: python, sql, pyspark

I am new to spark and and SQL and I am trying to do some queries. Currently I have a dataframe(df) with a bunch of columns but I am interested in 4 columns which I select and they look something like this:

```
Start   Stop   Price  Distance
  1      2      10       2
  1      3      20       4
  1      4      30       3
  1      1      5        2
  1      2      15       4
  1      2      25       6
  2      1      10       3
  3      2      30       5
```

What I need is to find top 5 start-stop points by the count of number of trips between the two points. If there is a tie, then the tie breaker is another column price_rate which is calculated by the average price between the two locations. So the answer should look something like what is shown below where 4.166 is (10+15+25)/(2+4+6)

```
Start   Stop   Count  Price_Rate
  1      2      3       4.166
  1      4      1       10.00
  3      2      1        6.00
  1      3      1        5.00
  2      1      1        3.33
```

What I did so far was

```
df2 = df.withColumn('Price_rate', col('Price')/col('Distance'))  
df3 = df2.select(['Start','Stop','Price_rate'])\
         .orderBy(col("Price_rate").desc())\
         .groupBy("Start","Stop")\
         .count().orderBy(col('count).desc())
```

This definitely doesn't work because I am not averaging the price rate but just ordering it in descending order. I am not sure how to call the query so I can aggregate the average and then group by the count. Any hints would be helpful. I know there are ways of just calling a SQL query as well so either way would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.agg()` function to group by and aggregate:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.groupBy("Start", "Stop").agg(F.count("*").alias("Count"), (F.sum("Price")/F.sum("Distance"))\
        .alias("Price_Rate")).orderBy(["Count", "Price_Rate"], ascending=False).show()

+-----+----+-----+------------------+                                           
|Start|Stop|Count|        Price_Rate|
+-----+----+-----+------------------+
|    1|   2|    3| 4.166666666666667|
|    1|   4|    1|              10.0|
|    3|   2|    1|               6.0|
|    1|   3|    1|               5.0|
|    2|   1|    1|3.3333333333333335|
|    1|   1|    1|               2.5|
+-----+----+-----+------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped me understand a lot!